# General solutions for a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier

Given PDE : $$\cos(x+y) p + \sin(x+y) q = z ; $$
Find its General solution.
***Solution:***
Lagrange's Auxillary equations: $$\frac{dx}{\cos(x+y)} = \frac{dy}{\sin(x+y)} = \frac{dz}{z}\qquad .....{\rm eqn}.1 $$
Using the first two pairs derived : $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \tan(x+y) \qquad .....{\rm eqn}.2 $$ 
Using multipliers $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,-1,0)$ : $$\frac{dx+dy}{\cos(x+y) +\sin(x+y)}= \frac{dx-dy}{\cos(x+y) -\sin(x+y)} \qquad .....{\rm eqn}.3$$ 
Solving eqn.3 by integrating both sides,
gives me a solution $$c_1=e^{y-x}(\cos(x+y)+\sin(x+y)) \qquad ....{\rm solution}.1$$
For second solution, Using eqn.1 and eqn.3 :
$$\frac{dz}{z} =\frac{dx+dy}{\cos(x+y) +\sin(x+y)}  $$
$$\implies\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dx(1+\frac{dy}{dx})}{\cos(x+y)(1+\tan(x+y))}$$
From eqn.(2),
$$\implies\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dx(1+{\tan(x+y))}}{\cos(x+y)(1+\tan(x+y))}$$
$$\implies\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dx}{\cos(x+y)}$$
Integrating both sides, gives me
$$\implies\ln{z} = \ln|\sec(x+y)+\tan(x+y)|+ \ln{c_2}$$
$$\implies c_2= \frac{\sec(x+y)+\tan(x+y)}{z}\qquad .....{\rm solution}.2 $$
does  $$\phi( e^{y-z}(\cos(x+y)+\sin(x+y)),\frac{\sec(x+y)+\tan(x+y)}{z})=0$$ stand as a valid solution for given PDE $\cos(x+y) p + \sin(x+y) q = z $?

Comment: They are several mistakes in your calculus. But before that are you sure that there is no typo in the PDE $\cos(x+y) p + \sin(x+y) q = z$ ?

Comment: Eqs 1, 2, 3 are correct. Solution 1 from equation 3 is non-sens because there is no $u$ and no $z$ in equation 3. One can't integrate $\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dx}{\cos(x+y)}$ because $y$ in an unknown function of $x$. But one can integrate $\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dx+dy}{\cos(x+y)+sin(x+y)}$.

Comment: @JJacquelin replying to the prior comment, no there is no typo in the PDE, i have picked up the PDE from a standard book. 
However for later comment, thanks for pointing it out i actually did a typo there in **solution 1** , which i have edited now. Additionally, much grateful to you for pointing it out about the integration, it explains it out for me. 
I would attach the corrected answer in the comments for anyone who reads it ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the inputs from @JJacquelin && @Gonçalo, posting the updated solution for above PDE.

For second solution, Using eqn.1 and eqn.3 :
$$\implies\frac{dz}{z} =\frac{dx+dy}{\cos(x+y) +\sin(x+y)}  $$
$$\implies\frac{dz}{z} =\frac{d(x+y)}{\cos(x+y) +\sin(x+y)}  $$
let,$\quad x+y = t$ 
$$\implies\frac{dz}{z} =\frac{d(t)}{\cos(t) +\sin(t)}  $$
$$\implies\sqrt{2}.\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dt}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}).\cos(t)+(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}).\sin(t))}$$
$$\implies\sqrt{2}.\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dt}{sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+t))}$$
Integrating both sides,
$$\implies\sqrt{2}.\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{dt}{sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+t))}$$
$$\implies\sqrt{2}\ln|z| = \ln|\tan(\frac{1}{2}.(\frac{\pi}{4}+(x+y))|+ \ln{c_2}$$
$$\implies\sqrt{2}\ln|z| = \ln|{c_2}.\tan(\frac{1}{2}.(\frac{\pi}{4}+(x+y))|$$
Taking anti-log both sides,
$$\implies {c_2} = z^\sqrt{2}.\cot(\frac{1}{2}.(x+y+\frac{\pi}{4})) \qquad ....solution .02$$
$$\phi({c_1}, {c_2})= 0 $$ is a general solution of given PDE.

Comment: Your result is correct. You found the general solution on implicite form $\phi({c_1}, {c_2})= 0 $. The explicite form is : $$u(x,y)=\Bigg(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \Bigg)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } }F\bigg(e^{y-x}\Big(\cos(x+y)+\sin(x+y) \Big) \bigg)$$ $F$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: @JJacquelin oh, that's helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With the change of variables $(\xi,\eta)=(x+y,y)$, we may rewrite the PDE as
$$
(\sin\xi + \cos\xi)z_{\xi}+(\sin\xi) z_{\eta}=z, \tag{1}
$$
and the characteristic equations as
$$
\frac{d\xi}{\sin\xi + \cos\xi}=\frac{d\eta}{\sin\xi}=\frac{dz}{z}. \tag{2}
$$
The solution to
$$
\frac{d\xi}{\sin\xi + \cos\xi}=\frac{d\eta}{\sin\xi}\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{d\xi}{\sin\xi + \cos\xi}=\frac{dz}{z} \tag{3}
$$
yield, respectively,
$$
\eta=\frac{1}{2}\left(\xi-\ln|\sin\xi+\cos\xi|\right)+c_1
\implies e^{2\eta-\xi}(\sin\xi+\cos\xi)=C_1, \tag{4}
$$
and
$$
\ln |z|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left|\tan\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\xi+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]\right|=C_2. \tag{5}
$$
The general solution to the PDE $(1)$ is, therefore,
$$
F(C_1,C_2)=0, \tag{6}
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary differentiable function, and $C_1$, $C_2$ are given by Eqs. $(4)$ and $(5)$.

Comment: Thank-you so much for the detailed solution. You're a saviour _ / \ _